# difference between app access token and user access token

Tags: facebook-opengraph, access-token

What's the difference between app access token and user access token?

I noticed that userData from FB is different, but I can make OpenGraph action and post on user wall or send to friends wall.

Can I use app access token in OpenGraph action?

Answer (score 6):

App `access_token` allows you to make request to the Facebook API on behalf of an App rather than a User. This is useful, for example to:

- modify the parameters of your App
- create and manage test users
- read your application's insights
- publish content to Facebook *on behalf of a user* who has granted a publishing permission to your application

Now in the Open Graph area:

> If your app publishes on behalf of its users and requires an access
>   token with no expiration time, you should use an App Access Token. An
>   App Access Token is signed using your app secret and will not expire;
>   it will be invalidated if you re-key/reset your application secret.
>
> App Access Tokens should only be used when the posting functions are
>   originated directly from your servers in order to keep them private to
>   the app.
>   ...
>   App Access Tokens are especially useful when
>   publishing instances of “secure Open Graph actions”, Open Graph
>   actions that should only be published by your app, such as
>   achievements and game scores. In this specific example, a user is
>   prevented from gaming his/her score by publishing fake
>   scores/achievements using a user access token.

Please read the following documents:

- [Login as an App](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/)
- [Using App Access Tokens (Open Graph)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/)